# Best way to update software over the air

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates

I have many Windows devices in the field. Each one of them is connected using a SIM card to the Internet or a WiFi network.

I am looking for a robust way to update software on the device, both Windows updates and other application updates (so WSUS is not sufficient, as I understand).

My requirements are that:

1. The devices shall check with a dedicated server if an update is
   there to download.
2. An update can be downloaded to the device. If a network connection is lost and the download is stopped, each update will resume, instead of restarting, when the connection comes back up.
3. There needs to be a capability to test the updates on R&D devices before allowing the devices in the field to download them.
4. The download connection from each device uses HTTPS.
5. The UI for the server and the agents is installed on the devices.
6. There is update reporting on the server.
7. That server can be called using an API from C#, without the need to install an agent on each client device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet all of your requirements you need to use SCCM server. It is designed to deploy any type of packages (updates, software installations, even BIOS or firmware).

- You create collections of the devices in SCCM and can deploy anything
  by the timetable. You can do test deployments first to a limited scope of machines.
- The CCM client is installed to the clients having
  GUI interface, connecting to the distribution point server via http
  or https.
- CCM client reports its status and every deployment to the
  management server.
- You can monitor any device in real time on the server and push
  commands/deployments to it.
- There is an integrated reporting features in SCCM available via
  http/http
- SCCM is integrated with WSUS
- The client must be connected to the corporate network with LAN or VPN
  connection
- You can deploy all you want via Internet without VPN if SCCM is
  installed in Azure or any other cloud.

Take a note that's a complex but very powerful solution. You will need a separate SCCM guy to support it, and SCCM, of course, if not free.

there are some alternatives to them, but SCCM is a world-wide trend and company-level thing.

You may also look into:

- https://specopssoft.com/blog/a-smart-alternative-to-sccm/
- https://www.pdq.com/blog/best-alternative-to-sccm-pdq-deploy-pdq-inventory/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great Answer. The thing is that we do not use VPN in our devices. The devices are medical devices which can be connected using a SIM card to the Internet or a WiFi network. I think I need a server instance that I can query like Windows does for the Windows updates. Not inside a LAN/VPN. What do you say ?

Comment: It's a very bad idea NOT to use VPN. it's a must for corporate environment. Devices, specially medical devices exposed to Internet is a security breach. I would strongly recommend to use it. Please take a note - all corporate centralized management is based on the idea that all devices are inside or the corporate network, and hence, protected. Is it's not possible, you need to place some management servers in the cloud (e.g. in Azure) and publish services there. Look into Intune. Publishing SCCM in the cloud is also possible but complicated, VPN wont be required to access it.